# Java validate only values between 1 and 3

Tags: java, validation

I am trying to only accept integers between the values of 1 and 3 using a while loop and nested if statement in Java.

Anything outside of this range, produces an error message

The program should only accept integers between 1 and 3, any strings of text or decimal values should also produce the same error message and loop back to the original print statement (enter a number: )

The code below runs without any compiler errors although the statement || (a < 1 || a > 3)) will always produce the error message, regardless of the value.

If I was to delete this statement, the program will run and only accept integers of any value, (error message appearing when a string or decimal value is entered)

Could anyone help range this program, only accepting values of between 1 and 3, thanks.

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Validate {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

int a = 0;

while (true) {
    System.out.print("enter a number: ");


    if (!input.hasNextInt() || !input.hasNext() || (a < 1 || a > 3)) {

        System.out.println("Oops! "); 

        input.nextLine();
    }


    else { 
        a = input.nextInt();
        break;
    }
}
input.close();
System.out.println("a = " + a);


}
```

}

Comment: `(a < 1 && a > 4)` will never be true: a number cannot be less than one AND more than 4. What you want is `a < 1 || a > 3` (i.e. `a` is less than 1 OR `a` is greater than 3.)

Comment: Yes my mistake. Although now the program doesn't seem to accept any range. Instead will always display the error message

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to be careful of the order of expressions. If one of the 3 statements you wrote happens to be true then the code in the if curly braces will execute. You likely want something like this

```
if (!input.hasNextInt() || !input.hasNext()){
    if ((a > 1 || a < 3)){
        YourCode
    }
}
```

The biggest issue is that you need to remember that initially your integer "a" is set to "0". This always catches your first if condition meaning that a is never set!

Comment: Though, he wants numbers between 1 and 3. 5 is greater than 1 hence it would execute above. Try (a  > 1 && a < 3)

Answer (score 0):

You are not updating the value of `a`, so it's 0 all the time.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Validate {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int a = 0;
        boolean loop = true;

        while (loop) {
            System.out.print("enter a number: ");

            if (!input.hasNextInt() || !input.hasNext()) {

                System.out.println("Oops! ");
                input.nextLine();
            } else {
                a = input.nextInt();
                if (a <= 3 && a >= 1)
                    loop = false;
                else {
                    System.out.println("Oops! ");
                    input.nextLine();
                }

            }
        }

        input.close();
        System.out.println("a = " + a);

    }
}
```

EDIT:

[image: Program working]

Comment: Sergio Tx, thanks for the solution, although the program still produce the error message regardless of if the number is within the allowed range (1,2 or 3). I want the program to NOT allow strings, decimals and to only accept values between 1 and 3. If value of less than 1 or value greater than 3 is entered the loop should still produce the same error message, as if a string or decimal was entered

Comment: It does not allow strings or decimals. The problem is that I forgot <= and >= . Now it works ;)

Comment: Just a thought, to make the code more concise could you parse the data

Comment: I have actually never used the Scanner, so I don't know how it works apart from the basics. Does it really need parsing or it does it by itself when you use nextint